# The selector is not recognized by selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, cucumber

I have the following HTML code for a button:

```
<div class="link" data-background-color="#fb00ff" style="background-color: rgb(251, 0, 255);">
 <div data-replace-selector="paragraph/8429/field_link/en/default" class="field field--name-field-link field--type-link field--label-hidden field__item">
    <a href="/user/login#skip-onboard" style="" xpath="1">Guests</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-replace-selector="paragraph/8429/field_link/en/default" class="field field--name-field-link field--type-link field--label-hidden field__item">
  <a href="/user/login#skip-onboard" style="" xpath="1">Guests</a>
</div>
<a href="/user/login#skip-onboard" style="" xpath="1">Guests</a>
```

And I want to click the button using Selenium Java.
What I tried:
The following selectors:

- XPath: `//*[@id='block-onboardingblock']/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a`
- CSS: `#block-onboardingblock > div > div.footer-buttons.direction-column > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > a`
- Full xpath: `/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/section/div/div/div[5]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a`

Java code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", selector);
```

or

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", selector);
```

How I can click the button?

Comment: Could you please edit your post to add HTML including the onboarding block? You might also try adding any errors you receive with your attempts so far.

Comment: Sure, thank you for the improvement, I don't receive any error, just I saw that the button is not clicked. Also, I add a JavaScript executor with a border to try to understand why it's not clicked.

Answer (score 0):

To click the button using Selenium Java, you can try using a different selector that uniquely identifies the element. In your case, you can use the following CSS selector to locate the button:

```
By cssSelector = By.cssSelector("div.link a[href='/user/login#skip-onboard']");
WebElement button = driver.findElement(cssSelector);
button.click();
```

Here, the CSS selector targets the `<a>` element within the `<div class="link">` that has an `href` attribute value of `"/user/login#skip-onboard"`. This selector should uniquely identify the button element you want to click.

Alternatively, if you prefer using the `JavascriptExecutor`, you can modify your code as follows:

```
By cssSelector = By.cssSelector("div.link a[href='/user/login#skip-onboard']");
WebElement button = driver.findElement(cssSelector);

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", button);
```

By using the above code snippets, you should be able to click the button successfully.

Another possible CSS selector is:

```
By cssSelector = By.cssSelector("div.link > div.field__item > a[href='/user/login#skip-onboard']");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesn't work. I tried all 3 variants but...nothing. Also, I tried with a Webdriver Wait and again, it doesn't work

Comment: The issue is that I have 2 buttons with the same HTML code (same url) but the names of the buttons are different